# Check string to see what's being added in Java

Tags: java

I have a chemistry compound ex 'H' and I want to add either 'H', 'C', 'O' or 'N' to it. How can I check in code which one I am adding to the current compound?

Second when I am adding to my current compound it might be H2. So if I added H it would become H2H but I want it to be H3, how can I fix this?

I am not really sure what to do coding wise but

```
String Compound = "H2";
String a="H";
String b="C";
String c="O";
string d="N";

if (I am adding "H" to Compound){

//do something

}

if(I am adding "C" to Compound) {

//do something else

}
```

Comment: can you provide what you are expecting for the function to do? It's not clear to me.

Comment: Be more specific.  Some sample code would be very helpful.

Comment: I want to check what I am adding to it. For example if I have H, I want to check if I added another 'H', or a 'C' or 'N' or 'O'.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I feel like I have seen this exact same question in 3 other places...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the things easier to understand and more ***object-oriented***, I think using a `Compound` class of your own might work as desired.

```
class Compound {
    String last;
    String compound;
    int lastSuffixCount;

    Compound() {
        this.last = "";
        this.compound = "";
        this.lastSuffixCount = 0;
    }

    public String getCompound() {
        return compound;
    }

    public void setCompound(String compound) {
        this.compound = compound;
    }

    public void add(String suffix, int times) {
        if (suffix.equals(this.last) && times > 0) 
        {
            this.compound = compound.replace(lastSuffixCount + "", "");
            this.lastSuffixCount = lastSuffixCount + times;
            this.compound += lastSuffixCount;
        } else if (times > 0) {
            this.compound += suffix + times;
        }
        this.lastSuffixCount = times;
        this.last = suffix;
    }
}
```

**Sample driver program:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Compound c = new Compound();
    c.add("H", 2);
    System.out.println(c.getCompound());
    c.add("H", 1);
    System.out.println(c.getCompound());
    c.add("O", 6);
    c.add("H", 4);
    System.out.println(c.getCompound());
}
```

**Output:**

```
H2
H3
H3O6H4
```

Comment: I agree, OO is the answer. However, rather than storing the compound as a String within the Compound class, use a collection of Objects instead. For example, using a Map<Element,Integer> might work nicely, mapping Elements (i.e.  'H', 'C', 'O' or 'N') to counts. Then you can easily convert the Map's data into the correct string representation. With this design the "H2" + 'H' = "H3" problem becomes trivial!

Comment: thanks for your help. I just have a question when I do something like
compound a;
a=new Compound();
a.setCompound("H");
a.add("C",1);

it will overwrite the previous compound and not add to the origianl, unless I have done something wrong

Comment: @Joe24 Please check my answer, I have included a sample driver. Accept my answer if it is useful for you.

Comment: thanks I really appreciate all your help. Could I just ask you one more thing? is there any slight modification I could make to the above code so that it would work if I did c.add("CH",1) and then did a c.add("H",1)?

Comment: @Joe24 you can do that, but it will take my and your time. instead, use `c.add("C",1);` first, then `c.add("H",1);`, then again `c.add("H",1);`. And also please accept the answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

You want to construct a regex that will capture capital letters, following lowercase letters, and numbers.  This will break down the formula into different elements and their counts.  Using a map to hold counts should work.

With an input like `C8H10N4O2`

You'll end up with something like:

```
{
  "C" : 8,
  "H" : 10,
  "N" : 4,
  "O" : 2
}
```

Do this with both operands, and add the counts together.

Iterate over the map's keys and put them together with their counts for your answer.  How you iterate over the keys will probably have to be decided by chemical nomenclature rules, of which I am blissfully ignorant.

Answer (score 0):

I feel a little confused about `(I am adding "C" to Compound)`

Do you want to detect if the string you adding contains "C" (or other String)?

use `String.indexOf(String s)`

example:

```
String c = "C";
String somethingAdding = "CH3";
if(somethingAdding.indexOf(c) == -1)
{
    // NOT adding C
}
else
{
    // adding C
}
```

But I really recommend you to make a Class to wrap the data, instead of using a string

Answer (score 0):

Here's my OO approach:

```
public class Compound {

    private static Pattern elementPattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]\\d*");

    private Map<Character, Integer> elements;

    public Compound(String compoundString) {
        elements = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

        Matcher matcher = elementPattern.matcher(compoundString);
        while(matcher.find()) {
            String elementAndCount = m.group()

            char element = elementAndCount.charAt(0);
            int count = (elementAndCount.length() > 1) ?
                    Integer.valueOf(elementAndCount.substring(1)) :
                    1;

            elements.put(element, count);
        }
    }

    public void addElement(Character element) {
        addElement(element, 1);
    }

    public void addElement(Character element, int count) {
        if (elements.containsKey(element)) {
            int currentCount = elements.get(element);
            elements.put(element, count + 1);
        } else {
            elements.put(element, 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder toReturn = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : elements.entrySet()) {
            toReturn.append("" + entry.getKey() + entry.getValue());
        }
        return toReturn.toString();
    }
}

            if (element
```